# Prevent column text overlapping

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have this code to show a column chart http://jsfiddle.net/Emerald214/wCDnK/8/. The problem is it has many many columns (about 100), how to prevent column text to overlap each other.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            //zoomType: 'x'
        },

        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },

    legend: {
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        align: 'right'
    },

        xAxis: {
            minRange: 1
        },


        xAxis : {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', '11', '22', '33', '44', '55', '66', '77', '88', '99', '111', '222', '333', '444', '555']
        },

        series: [{    
            data: [1111, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555]        
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: You can try rotating the label little bit to make it bit visible like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wCDnK/9/ else try increasing the width of your chart

Comment: Rolled back, please don't make pointless edits such as changing one word to italic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the labels on the x-axis:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels/grid.

You add this setting when you use HighChart, here the call with rotation: -90, I removed the rest of the code for clarity, but here's the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({              
            series: [{               
                dataLabels: {
                    rotation: -90,
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: What if the labels are so long that rotating doesn't looks well? Is there a way for long label texts and 100 columns?

Comment: I guess in that case you need to pull out some design changes, decrease letter size, increade bar wdth, or even rotate the labels to be upright or something, or maybe a solotion which removes the labels and shows them on hover? However you place them, you need the  physical pixels for your labels :)

Comment: What a difficult problem! I have about 100 columns with about-10-character strings. They overlaps and make a black mess. I wonder if Highcharts has a smart way to show it (combined with zooming).

Comment: Another idea, you kan stagger the labels so they alternate between two lines,, having the first label on line one, the second on line two, the 3th on line on again. Here's some examplecode for highcharts: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7123

Comment: hehe I did but it's still a big black mess. I wonder if there is a way to group some columns to something (or paging). Still researching it but I find it weird when a chart has so many columns. That's weird! (but it's a requirement from customer)